# Is it "China, People's Republic" or "China, People's Republic of"?

Tags: nouns

Which one is correct for the country name of China,  "China, People's Republic" or "China, People's Republic of"? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think either form could be incorrect. This might be more of a style question.

Comment: This isn't a question of grammar or usage, but of style; however, I would find it strange to omit the preposition, considering the name would only be written this way in a list or a table alphabetized by country name. FWIW, the ISO 3166 name is simply *China* (contra *Taiwan, Province of China*) with the full name *[the] People's Republic of China*, which is also the convention used by most Western media and governments.

Comment: I believe it's "中华人民共和国".

Answer (score 1):

China is officially the "People's Republic of China (PRC)".

Obviously, the main reason to invert the word ordering would be so that "China" appears alphabetically in lists under the letter C.

A Google search for "China, People's Republic" reveals the following results on many different websites:

> "China, People's Republic of"
>
> "China, People's Republic"
>
> "China, (People's Republic of)"
>
> "China, (People's Republic)"

As written in an earlier comment "*I would find it strange to omit the preposition.*"

Still... all of the above choices are reasonably clear, understandable, and do appear in current texts, which therefore gives them all some degree of validity.